# Is there a specific guideline to follow when orchestrating services with WSO2?

Tags: rest, wso2, integration, esb

I'm currently writing a document during an internship regarding the WSO2 Enterprise Integrator.

Problem is, I'm not going to work with it and definitely not going to write a single line of code, yet my job would be creating some guidelines that dictate how services (both SOAP and REST) should be orchestrated through the ESB.

The WSO2 documentation isn't helping me a lot because it mostly delves into explaining how to set up the Integrator and what tools are avaiable, and online I can only find simple tutorials which I can't really understand anyway because, as I said, I'm not even working with the platform.

So basically I don't understand if there is a specific conduct to follow when orchestrating services like "add this specific function in the service, create a dependency to the ESB" or whatever. 
Any form of suggestion or just directing me towards the right documentation would be super helpful

Answer (score 0):

Under my experience, what you must do is a proof of concept performing service orchestration, now by definition one of the characteristics of any ESB is precisely to be an orchestrator. I work daily with WSO2 and allows it in simple ways (with the same mediators) or complex ways (extending or creating new components)

PS: Excuse me for my English.

Regards !!!